# Python script - add file read as alternative option

Tags: python, argv

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

import threading
import requests
import Queue
import sys
import re

#ip to num
def ip2num(ip):
    ip = [int(x) for x in ip.split('.')]
    return ip[0] << 24 | ip[1] << 16 | ip[2] << 8 | ip[3]

#num to ip
def num2ip(num):
    return '%s.%s.%s.%s' % ((num & 0xff000000) >> 24,(num & 0x00ff0000) >> 16,(num & 0x0000ff00) >> 8,num & 0x000000ff)

def ip_range(start, end):
    return [num2ip(num) for num in range(ip2num(start), ip2num(end) + 1) if num & 0xff]

def bThread(iplist):
    threadl = []
    queue = Queue.Queue()
    for host in iplist:
        queue.put(host)

    for x in xrange(0, int(SETTHREAD)):
        threadl.append(tThread(queue))

    for t in threadl:
        t.start()
    for t in threadl:
        t.join()

#create thread
class tThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):

        while not self.queue.empty():
            host = self.queue.get()
            try:
                checkServer(host)
            except:
                continue

def checkServer(host):
    ports = [80]

    for k in ports:
        try:
            aimurl = "http://"+host+":"+str(k)

            response = requests.get(url=aimurl,timeout=3)
            serverText = response.headers['server']

            if (response.status_code) == 403:
                print  "-"*50+"\n"+aimurl +" Server: "+serverText

        except:
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print '\n#############        CDN IP     #############'
    print '                                                '
    print '################################################\n'

    global SETTHREAD

    try:
        SETTHREAD = sys.argv[2]

        iplist = []
        file = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
        tmpIpList = file.readlines()
        for ip in tmpIpList:
            iplist.append(ip.rstrip("\n"))

        print '\nEscaneando '+str(len(iplist))+" IP's...\n"

        bThread(iplist)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print 'Keyboard Interrupt!'
        sys.exit()
```

This script works as follows, a range of ip is entered:

```
python2 script.py 104.0.0.0-104.0.1.255 100 (100 is the number of threads)
```

I want to add support so that it reads the ip of a file, and that the range also works.

```
python2 script.py ips.txt 100
```

I tried this:

```
file = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
    iplist = file.readlines()
```

But it does not work.

Edit1: added file reading code recommended by user Syed Hasan, the problem seems to be the bThread(iplist) function

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean?

Comment: @blackbrandt the script just stops... it doesn't do its job

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're attempting to use 'iplist' the same way as your CLI input was attempting to parse it. However, the `readlines` function simply reads the entire file at once and appends a `newline (\n)` at the end (provided you do format the IPs with a succeeding newline character).

Currently, you should be getting a list of IPs with a succeeding newline character. Try removing it from the rightmost end using `rstrip`:

```
file = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
tmpIpList = file.readlines()
for ip in tmpIpList:
    iplist.append(ip.rstrip("\n"))
```

How you switch between the two modes is a challenge you should attempt to solve. Perhaps use command-line parameter support to identify the mode of operations (look into the **argparse** library).

Comment: I tried as you mention, but the variable iplist is not defined

Comment: Simply define it. A list. `iplist = []`

Comment: apparently the problem is the bThread (iplist) function, any suggestion

Comment: How about you update the code in the post? This is all mixed up right now.

Comment: ready add the code, the reading of the ip lines makes it correct, the problem comes when scanning